# Netty 4 - changing channel's eventloop

Tags: netty

My question is about changing channel's eventloop of an already registred channel.

A channel is bound to an io-eventloop thread, coming from EventLoopGroup setted on the serverboostrap. Ok. 
But after "protocol negociation" I want to change the io-eventloop of some channel to a dedicated io-eventloop. 
So I do something like this:

```
        channel.deregister().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

          @Override
          public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {

            newIoLoop.register(future.channel()).sync();
          }
        });
```

All work well but one question:
channel.eventloop is updated and newer ChannelHandlerContext will be created with this eventloop.
But channel.pipeline.head is still bound to the old eventloop.
Is this the expected behavior?

This generate an exception raised by AbstractNioByteChannel.NioByteUnsafe.read() method:

```
  case 2:
  // Let the inbound handler drain the buffer and continue reading.
  if (read) {
    read = false;
    pipeline.fireInboundBufferUpdated(); // event fired in the pipeline to try to read some bytes but without waiting for handler executed in another loop
    if (!byteBuf.writable()) {  // byteBuf may always be full and exception is raised
        throw new IllegalStateException(
          "an inbound handler whose buffer is full must consume at " +
                      "least one byte.");
    }
  }
```

In my case, changing pipeline.head.eventloop when changing channel registration will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug.. can you please open a bug-report on our issue tracker on github ?

Thanks!